# Windows 10 ~ Irregular Partial Blackscreen on Login

Tags: windows-10, login, black-screen-of-death

The following has happened to be almost a dozen times in the last few months:

After starting the computer, the login screen appeared as normally, and I was able to login. However, after the login, the only thing appearing on the screen are my mouse, a black background, and the Hard Disk Sentinel program I installed.

I can bring up the cut-screen by pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Delete] and log out from there, and when I log in everything works as normal, but since this jsut keeps on happening I sort of want to do something against it.

I have already disabled fast startup, but it still happens. The interesting thing is that my keyboard - which has colored key backlighting - actually reliably indicates when this bug happens even before login: If the keys are not lit as I configured them, then this error will occur 100% of the time, so I figure maybe it's conencted to windows not starting most of its standard programs, including the explorer?

Anyway, I've actually logged the days on which this occurred, but wasn't able to figure out a pattern, but since i have that data I figure I might as well post it here. It happened on these days, each time after I switched on the computer in the morning (I keep the power off over night):

- 02-Feb-2021
- 20-Feb-2021
- 22-Feb-2021
- 08-Mar-2021
- 09-Mar-2021
- 14-Mar-2021
- 15-Mar-2021
- 26-Mar-2021
- 30-Mar-2021
- 31-Mar-2021
- 20-Apr-2021

Does anyone have an idea about what's causing this, and what can be done about it?

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I checked the event viewer, and noticed some errors. Since the error messages are in German, I'll just summarize and paraphrase them.

- First, LogonUI.exe fails
- Then windows can't access the file C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Globalization.dll
- Then, Explorer.exe fails, because windows can't access the file C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Comment: Could you check event viewer and compare login having issue and normal login?

Comment: As above. Namely look for entries about HDD Sentinel, something that probably you want to uninstall anyway.